# Use fmpp command line parameter in template

Tags: freemarker, fmpp

I have some configuration templates which use FMPP to generate the 
real runtime config files based upon info in a csv and properties
file (defined in config.fmpp).

I want to be able to configure a second cluster server for the same task using the same set of templates and config.fmpp information.  However, there are slight differences needed in the generated runtime config and I can do this if I know which server instance I am on ("serverA" or "serverB") using a standard fmpp variable like `${myserver}`.

But there must only be one set of templates and FMPP config files so I need to somehow get the value of "myserver" from the runtime 
environment in each server.

Some of the options I might have are:

- pass value of myserver on the command line tool invocation (best way); or
- get it from an environment variable.

Does anyone have an example of the code to do any of these and any suggestions  of the best approach? Online reference would be great.

```
fmpp -S /home/me/sample-project/src -Param myserver:serverA
```

Environment settings:

- fmpp v0.9.14
- freemarker v2.3.19

Comment: -D myserver:serverA

Comment: but it is looking for it in the templates! : Source file or directory not found: C:\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\OPP\temp\C-
fgTplt1525284376510_0\isoserverTemplates\ -D myserver:serverA

Comment: It doesn't even  seem to recognize -D as a flag

Comment: the path in the message is also not the data path specified with -C, it is the -S path

Answer (score 1):

Use the `-D` command line option (see `--help`):

```
-D, --data=<TDD>  Creates shared data that all templates will see. <TDD> is the
                  Textual Data Definition, e.g.:
                  -D "properties(style.properties), onLine:true"
                  Note that paths like "style.properties" are relative to the
                  data root directory.
```

Like:

```
fmpp -S /home/me/sample-project/src -D myserver:serverA
```

Note that there's a space after the `-D`. (It's not like the java command line syntax, but rather like the standard GNU command line syntax.

> This `-D` has nothing to do with Java's `-D` option.

The [documentation](http://fmpp.sourceforge.net/commandline.html) shows `onLine:true`, but such Boolean values are legacy and no longer accepted. Use `online:yes` to parse Boolean values.

For example:

```
fmpp \
  -S /path/ \
  --verbose \
  -D "online:yes"
```

Then, within the template:

```
<p>
  online: ${online}
</p>
```

Will result in:

```
online: yes
```

The `--verbose` command-line parameter is useful to show any errors when parsing the template.

Comment: isn't this exactly what I said I tried???  And it gave the above error: Source file or directory not found: C:\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\OPP\temp\C- fgTplt1525284376510_0\isoserverTemplates\ -D myserver:serverA

Comment: `-D` is not a new option, but FMPP doesn't complain that it doesn't recognize it either. It seems that the whole thing shown as the "source file or directory" is passed to FMPP as a single big command line argument. How exactly do you invoke it?

Comment: int exitCode = CommandLine.execute(new String[] {"-C", isoserverTemplatesDataPath + "config.fmpp", 
   "-S", isoserverTemplatesPath, "--data-root", isoserverTemplatesDataPath, "-O", 
   isoserverFilledTemplatesPath}, null, null);  // process the templates with FMPP

Comment: Looks fine to me, though there's no `-D` in this. What's up with that? (BTW, while `CommandLine.execute` should definitely work, note that it's maybe nicer to use the `Settings` API to set up and launch an FMPP job. See: http://fmpp.sourceforge.net/writefrontend.html)